# MySQL Workbench Model - Hide SQL query in model table panels

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is there a way to hide the SQL query in model panels for tables that are linked to other tables?  The part I want hidden is the yellow highlighted query below.  I want the table panels to show the schema/columns for the table for that panel, not anything else.  In the below case, just that table's three columns.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a query what you see there but a list of columns in that table as well as the indexes in it.

However, you can individually hide indexes or all fields in a table figure by collapsing the related parts, by clicking on the small triangles.

Comment: Sure, not a query, but it shows indexes from other linked tables in the model.  I just want to see the table's own columns (3 in this case) and not related tables indexes.  Closing the 'Indexes' section still shows related tables indexes...see updated question

Comment: What I wrote is all you can do. It's not possible to hide individual columns. You can also change the hide of the table figure so that it only shows the elements you want.